# Bootstrap tags input & Bootstrap select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, tags

in my script, I would like to make sure, that the site, once the tags loaded, to change the values in the drop-down menu. However, what does not work is that, the site only performs the operation for the last drop-down menu on the page.

Libraries used:

- [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)
- [Bootstrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Here my jquery code:

```js
$('[name^=tagsquiz]').on('itemAddedOnInit', function(event) {
 tags = $(this).val();
 idtags = $(this).prop('id').substr(13);
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'tags/select',
  data: {
   'tags': tags
  },
  success: function(array) {
   var html = '';
   var count = 1;
   $('#noqid_' + idtags).empty();
   $.each(JSON.parse(array), function(i, ob) {
    $.each(ob, function(ind, obj) {
     html += '<option value="' + count + '">' + (count++) + '</option>';
    });
   });
   $('#noqid_' + idtags).html(html);
   $('#noqid_' + idtags).selectpicker('refresh');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <label class="control-label">Tags</label> <input class="tagsinput" data-color="rose" data-role="tagsinput" id="tagsfilterid_1" name="tagsquiz[]" type="text" value="test">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <label class="control-label">Select</label> <select class="selectpicker" data-none-selected-text="NO RESULT" data-size="7" data-style="select-with-transition" id="noqid_1" name="noq[]">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <label class="control-label">Tags</label> <input class="tagsinput" data-color="rose" data-role="tagsinput" id="tagsfilterid_add" name="tagsquiz[]" type="text" value="second test, wow">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <label class="control-label">Select</label> <select class="selectpicker" data-none-selected-text="NO RESULT" data-size="7" data-style="select-with-transition" id="noqid_add" name="noq[]">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example array receive after ajax:

```
{"questions":{"0":{"qid":"48"},"2":{"qid":"50"}}}
```

Best regards

Comment: Please combine two snippets in one. Then move `success` function from `$.ajax` as separate function, because we don't know what data is in the ajax response (fill `array` with predefined values).

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase I change it, and I put a exemple array receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this widget, but I suspect your problem is here:

```
idtags = $(this).prop('id').substr(13);
```

How many elements are in the jQuery collection returned by `$(this)`?  How many times does your `itemAddedOnInit` function execute?  If it's more than one time, is the value of `idtags` different each time?

The [jQuery `prop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) returns "the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements."  One way or another, I suspect that there's only ever one value of `idtags`, and that this line...

```
$('#noqid_' + idtags)
```

only ever matches one element.

#### Update

It appears the issue stems from not using the `var` keyword in the following lines...

```
tags = $(this).val();
idtags = $(this).prop('id').substr(13);
```

Omitting `var` makes them global variables, and therefore both executions of the `itemAddedOnInit` share them.

Comment: itemAddedOnInit is execute 2 times in this case (Execute for every tags field). `idtags` is suppose to be different like you see in the snippet. How can I correct this, to have multiple value of this ?

Comment: Are you saying that you know -- based on observation -- that (1) the function is executed 2 times, but (2) the value of `idtags` is the same both times?  That would be helpful.  Loop the elements (maybe with `$('.selectpicker').each(...)`) inside the `success` function.

Comment: Ok, I juste test it. When I do a alert before the ajax, I get `1` and `add`, but if do it in the success, I obtain: `add` and `add`... It looks like the ajax select the value of `idtags` only one time, I don't understand why.

Comment: Where is `var idtags` declared?  Is it a global variable?  It should probably be declared in the portion of code you posted... inside the `itemAddedOnInit` function... so that it's scoped to each invocation of that function.  I think they're colliding.

Comment: What I post, is the only place there is the variable `idtags`. So it's in the `itemAddedOnInit`.

Comment: You want to use the `var` keyword:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it

Comment: Thank you, in addition to working, I learned a few things today!

Answer (score 0):

It is because all your tags have identical attributes. You have to use JQuery each function as, 
**`$('.control-label').each(function(){
// Your code here
});`**